# How to solve Type Property '' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Function'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component like so

```
import filterComponent from 'filter/filterComponent'


  const reloadHandler = useCallback(
    (event: MouseEvent) => {
      event.preventDefault();
     // my logic
    },
    [Reload, Fetching]
  );

const parent = () => { 
return (
    <filterComponent reload={reloadHandler} /> 
   )
}
```

Filter Component:

```
export const filterComponent = (filter: Function, reload: Function) => { 
    return (
       <Button onClick={reload} />
   )
}
```

error:

> Type '{ reload: (e: MouseEvent) => void; }' is
>   not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Function'.   Property
>   'reload' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Function'

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it complains about the way you access properties in FilterComponent. Try this version:

```
type FilterComponentProps = {
  reload: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void,
};

export const FilterComponent = (props: FilterComponentProps) => { 
 return <button onClick={props.reload} />;
}
```

and then the component that calls it:

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const reloadHandler = React.useCallback(
    (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      // my logic
    },
    // I've removed dependencies as I'm not sure where you take them from
    [] 
  );
  return (
    <FilterComponent reload={reloadHandler} /> 
  )
}
```

Also note that I've changed `filterComponent` to be `FilterComponent` as [lowercase component namespace is reserved for HTML primitives](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

I've also composed you a CodeSandbox (just in case): https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-3i7cm